# How to move to parent directory with LeaderF?

Tags: vimrc, neovim

When I'm browsing folders in [LeaderF](https://github.com/Yggdroot/LeaderF) is there a way to move to the parent folder?

Background: I'm building a vim (Neovim) profile and looking at file/buffer explorers, and LeaderF seems useful. (I've used CtrlP previously and liked it; I can't make heads or tails of denite.) It makes sense that LeaderF starts in the same directory as the current file (I have `set autochdir`): this is usually what I want. However it seems to me that in many cases I would want to broaden the scope of my search by moving to the parent folder.

I expected that LeaderF would provide a binding for this and the fact that the functionality doesn't exist makes me think that I'm using it wrong.

How do others typically use LeaderF?

Comment: I haven't used LeaderF, but for me it makes sense that a fuzzy finder is pinned to the project root in some way. I normally keep Vim's notion of the current directory pinned to the project root because then everything is relative to that. CtrlP lets you control this behavior, where the default is to search up your directory tree until it finds a source control file/directory indicating the root (e.g. a `.git` folder), and use that to pin the search, but you can also have it use the current directory or Vim's working directory. LeaderF may have a similar setting.

Comment: @JimStewart LeaderF works this way, but in some cases you don't have `.git` or other project markers. So you try to open a file and there is current file directory+subdirectories list and no way to go up. The workaround is to close LeadefF and reopen it with `:LeaderfFile ..`

Answer (score 1):

I have similar setup (`set autochdir`) and sometimes I face the same issue for the folders without root markers (.git, .hg ...).

I was using workaround described in comment to your question -- close and reopen leaderf with parent folder:

```
:LeaderfFile ..
```

I have `cnoremap lf LeaderfFile` defined, so it is easy to type.

But today I have come up with the other solution.

You can change "normal" mappings of leadefF:

```
    let g:Lf_NormalMap = {
    \ "File":   [["u", ':LeaderfFile ..<CR>']]
    \}
```

This way you can press `<tab>` to go to LeaderfFile normal mode and then press `u` to reopen LeadefFile with parent folder.

PS,

There is also `g:Lf_CommandMap` that is used to remap some bindings in the prompt but I am not sure if I can run ex commands there.